# Form not looking good without using crispy form

Tags: python, django, forms, url, modelform

[image]

This is the form that appears if I donot use crsipy form.But, if I use crispy forms, the radio button disappears, anyone have any idea??

[image]

As shown above, if crispy form is used, the radio button now disapperas.what is the issue??

```
<form  method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|crispy }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction="{% url 'addcustomer' %}">Submit</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="{% url 'customerlist' %}">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: did you change bootstrap4 in your settings .py

Comment: I have bootstrap3 in my settings.py

Comment: change it to bootstrap4

Comment: Thanks a lottttt man, it works....It had wasted my entire 2 days!!! We had to put CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4' instead of 3 in my settings..thanks!!